# Why does the output change on this Python implementation of Depth First Search?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

So for depth-first search, I have an implementation in Python that goes like this:

```py
def dfs(graph, current_vertex, target_value, visited=None):
  if visited is None:
    visited = []

  visited.append(current_vertex)

  if current_vertex == target_value:
    return visited


  for neighbor in graph[current_vertex]:
    if neighbor not in visited:
      path = dfs(graph, neighbor, target_value, visited)

      if path:
        return path


my_graph = {
    'lava': set(['sharks', 'piranhas']),
    'sharks': set(['lava', 'bees', 'lasers']),
    'piranhas': set(['lava', 'crocodiles']),
    'bees': set(['sharks']),
    'lasers': set(['sharks', 'crocodiles']),
    'crocodiles': set(['piranhas', 'lasers'])
  }
```

but when I run `print(dfs(my_graph, "crocodiles", "bees"))`, sometimes I get `[‘crocodiles’, ‘piranhas’, ‘lava’, ‘sharks’, ‘lasers’, ‘bees’]`, and other times I get `[‘crocodiles’, ‘lasers’, ‘sharks’, ‘lava’, ‘piranhas’, ‘bees’]`, and other times I get: `[‘crocodiles’, ‘piranhas’, ‘lava’, ‘sharks’, ‘bees’]`. Why is the output different on the same input? Is this implementation even correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you haven't accounted for back tracking. Eg, say your DFS decides to go `[‘crocodiles’, ‘lasers’, ‘sharks’, ‘lava’, ‘piranhas’]`, which leads to a dead end. Now even though it has reached a dead end, `‘lava’, ‘piranhas’` has already been appended, so when you back track to `'sharks'` and correctly pick `'bees'`, the list is outputted incorrectly.

To fix this issue, you simply need to record `visited` prior to creating a path from the current node. Once the path is created, check to see if the target node is present, and if it isn't, set `visited` back to its original state:

```py
def dfs(graph, current_vertex, target_value, visited=None):
  if visited is None:
    visited = []

  visited.append(current_vertex)

  if current_vertex == target_value:
    return visited


  for neighbor in graph[current_vertex]:
    if neighbor not in visited:
      orig = list(visited)
      path = dfs(graph, neighbor, target_value, visited)
      if path and target_value in path:
        return path
      visited = list(orig)
```

EDIT:

Also I should note what the `list(visited)` and `list(orig)` is for. The reason for this is to (in this case) deep copy the lists. That means modifying one will be total independent of the other. **This only works for lists of depth 1**. If a list has a depth > 1, you will simply copy a reference to the lists inside the list, and run in to the same issues. In this case, use `deepcopy` from `copy` by importing it as follows:

`from copy import deepcopy`

Edit 2:

It is better to do it the following way, as you don't have to store a copy of the list:

```
def dfs(graph, current_vertex, target_value, visited=None):
  if visited is None:
    visited = []

  visited.append(current_vertex)

  if current_vertex == target_value:
    return visited


  for neighbor in graph[current_vertex]:
    if neighbor not in visited:
      path = dfs(graph, neighbor, target_value, visited)
      if path and target_value in path:
        return path
      visited.pop(-1)
```

Comment: Isn't it simpler to pop the last element off `visited` after the for loop?

Comment: Yeh, that is a better way of doing it, uses less memory.

Comment: `visited.pop()` even; `-1` is the default argument. I also prefer putting the `pop` outside of the `for` loop, I think it's tidier to have the visiting function both append itself then remove itself from `visited`. But clearly this is personal preference.

Comment: i still get different results time to time when I go with the second implementation you've presented

Comment: In the case you presented with the dictionary you put in the answer, I don't see how that is possible. However, if yo were to use another dictionary where there are multiple valid paths from the start node and end node, then because you are initialising the dictionary values with `set` rather then `list`, it will randomly choose the order, hence the different result each time. If you want a consistent result, use a standard list.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Python, sets doesn't have a specific order. You might want to use lists instead of sets.

Comment: This is what I suspected would give the different outputs, it doesn't, however, account for the fact that OP was getting an output such as `[‘crocodiles’, ‘lasers’, ‘sharks’, ‘lava’, ‘piranhas’, ‘bees’]`, which shouldn't be possible given `'bees'` is connected only to `'sharks'`

Comment: @Recessive OP has done DPS if it doesn't occur then it goes to back to the previous vertex and tries to find all its neighbours in which one of them is "bees"

Comment: Yeh, the problem is OP hasn't accounted for back tracking

Comment: Don't dicts respect insertion order as of 3.6?

Comment: @ATayler Yes, but the ordering of the dict doesn't affect to the search, since it is accessed by index, not by iteration. The only randomness here is in the set iteration order.

Comment: @JuanCarlos indeed. You should edit your answer to fix the implementation as well as the non-determinism, it seems wasteful to create another answer. I think it's also worth noting that OP need only change sets => lists if they want deterministic results, there's nothing a priori wrong with having a non-det search.